# Failed to fetch packages

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, update-manager, vlc

```
Failed to fetch http: security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vlc/libvlccore7_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http: security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vlc/libvlc5_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http: security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vlc/vlc-nox_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http: security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vlc/vlc_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http: security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vlc/vlc-plugin-notify_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http: security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vlc/vlc-plugin-pulse_2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found
```

Comment: Describe your problem concisely, please. What have you done? Did you search on the internet for answer?

Answer (score 1):

There has been a security update for VLC since you last updated your package lists. The current version of VLC in 14.04 is 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2, packages for 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 are not available any more.

Run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update your package lists. After that you should be able to install VLC.